# Question about bdist directory hierarchy

Tags: python, distutils

I just made a small app and then wrote a `setup.py` file for it. Everything seems to be working, except I can't figure out a small thing.

When passing the `bdist` option to `setup.py`, it creates the archive gzipped tar file. When I open that file, I notice that the directory structure is:

```
> usr
  > lib
    > python2.6
      > site-packages 
        > Folder 1
        > Folder 2
```

What is the reason for this? Typically, I had expect that Folder 1 and Folder 2 would be in the root directory. Why does `bdist` add the top level directories? Is there any way I can get rid of them (more importantly, should I get rid of them?)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want an sdist output .... so try python setup.py sdist

Quote of Python documentation

> As a simple example, if I run the following command in the Distutils source tree:

```
python setup.py bdist
```

> then the Distutils builds my module distribution (the Distutils itself in this case), does a “fake” 
>    installation (also in the build directory), and creates the default type of built distribution for my platform. The default format for built distributions is a “dumb” tar file on Unix, and a simple executable installer on Windows. (That tar file is considered “dumb” because it has to be unpacked in a specific location to work.)

See [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html)